# displaing javascript strings in two different lines

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to display an array value in frontend angular. how can i add space between string and display them in two different lines.

```
x: any = []
x[{info: "test" + ',' + "tested"}]


// instead of displaying 
test , tested

// i want to display it in two different lines

test,
tested
```

please someone guide me on how can i achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you display it? If you're inserting it as a text node into HTML, then you need to use `<br />` tags. If you're printing it in the console, then you should use `\n` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set css style

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

to the current element

and

```
x[{info: "test" + '\n' + "tested"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a break line

```
x[{info: "test" + ',' + "<br>tested"}]
```